# Call Perl Script from Batch File

Tags: windows, perl, batch-file

I'm trying to make a batch file that will call a perl script that I have created that reports data every minute to a program. The program is not able to open perl scripts in Windows, but can collect data if a batch file opens the program.

So far I have this:

```
@echo off
call "C:\[Perl Installation Location for reporting program]\manager\etc\perl.exe" "C:\[Script location on disk]\program.pl"
```

However this returns the error

> Can not find scrict.pm

Any suggestions?

Edit: Removing Use Strict and Use Warnings fixed the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Does your script have a line `use scrict;` in it, because someone's typoed `use strict;`?

Comment: You should use `start` or `start` rather than `call` (type `start /?` for help); moreover I suggest you execute the line directly by typing it in command prompt, maybe the problem is something else...

Comment: Getting rid of use strict and use warnings allowed the script to run. Thanks sobrique!

Comment: Fixing the typo would probably be a better solution.

Comment: Fix the typo! Don't rip out the safety mechanisms!

Answer (score -1):

try this

inside the bat file

```
cd /d script_path
perl tescript_name
```